# How to create a composite primary key in my document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create primary keys using name and ssn.

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "students",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "_prfVnIB9H5oRoSoC",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "name" : Sam,
      "age" : "23",
      "SSN" : "2365PK",
      "Class" : "10",
      "School" : "St jose School "
     }
 ]
```

I am trying something like this, I don't think this is correct :

```
  PUT students/_doc/_create
   {
     "name" : "ssn"
    }
```

Here is the code where I'm sending the data to elasticsearch :

```
 String newESURL = esUrl + "/students/_doc";
        int diplayCount = 0;
        for (; rec < Records.size(); rec++) {
            String StudRecord = Obj.writeValueAsString(Records.get(rec));
            String Resp = given().trustStore("keystore/cacerts", "xyz").baseUri(newESURL).contentType("application/json").accept("application/json")
                    .body(StudRecord)
                    .auth().basic(User, Password)
                    .post().then().extract().body().asString();
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want your `_id` to be a compound key made of name and SSN?

Comment: No, I want to have composite primary key of name and ssn in my whole document.

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by "primary key". In ES, the primary key is the `_id` field.

Comment: okay.. how to use document id for achieving this..? I know there is no direct way to create primary key in elasticsearch

Comment: How do you index your documents?

Comment: I haven't done any specific thing for indexing , it is the default one.. I'm not much aware of ES ..

Comment: Do you care to explain what is your use case exactly? What are you trying to achieve, etc...

Comment: yes... I have created one index which is having few documents which will get loaded on daily basis, so I don't need duplicates to load , therefore I want to have primary key with these 2 fields..

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the role of the `_id` field I was talking about.

Comment: okay..Can you please tell me how to do that.. I 'm using java code and restlevelclient to push data daily

Comment: What tool do you use to "load the documents on a daily basis"?

Comment: I am querying a database and the resultset is pushed to the elasticsearch using a scheduler

Comment: Well, maybe you at least need to show the code that calls the index API...

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There we go. Here is the modified code that would achieve what you need:

```
String newESURL = esUrl + "/students/_doc/";
    int diplayCount = 0;
    for (; rec < Records.size(); rec++) {
        Record = record = Records.get(rec);
        String StudRecord = Obj.writeValueAsString(record);
        String StudentKey = "TODO";
        String Resp = given().trustStore("keystore/cacerts", "xyz")
                .baseUri(newESURL + StudentKey)
                .contentType("application/json")
                .accept("application/json")
                .body(StudRecord)
                .auth().basic(User, Password)
                .put().then().extract().body().asString();
```

Where you see `"TODO"`, you need to create a compound key using the `name` and `SSN` fields of the record and join them together, e.g. `john-123-456-6789`
So the URL is actually different for each record because it contains the ID (i.e. primary key) of your record. This will prevent duplication on subsequent loads.

Also make sure to use `put()` instead of `post()`